# Using sub parser for mutual exclusive flag options

Tags: python, argparse

I've written a small program that uses argparse. I have 3 flags in particular that I want to prevent being used in combination. I've created some code to achieve this, however it doesn't seem very elegant. Should I use sub_parsers for this? The examples that I've found here seem to address more complex flag options such as creating flag combinations that can be ran together and limiting combinations with other flags.

Here's what I've put together:

```
parser.add_argument(-a) 
parser.add_argument(-b) 
parser.add_argument(-c) 
args = parser.parse_args() 

count = 0 
for item in [args.a, args.b, args.c]: 
  if item is not None: 
    count += 1 

if count > 1: raise Exception
```

It gets the job done but I feel like my loop and count is makeshift at best. Is there a better way? Is sub_parser meant for this scenario?

Comment: why are your flags mutually exclusive? If they are used to send the program into 3 different tasks, sub_parsers might make sense, but you should probably be fine using choices (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices), where you have only one argument with one of three values to be associated with

Comment: You can add mutually exclusive groups to `argparse` directly. Check the docs! https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group

Comment: The actual flag names are --add --remove and --list. The Add and Remove flags take an argument. I felt these worked better as separate flags rather than just options under choices.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mutually exclusive groups. I had seen another post mentioning it, but there was negative commentary in the thread so I skipped right over it in the docs. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [add_mutually_exclusive_group()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) directly.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='MyFancyCLI')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-a')
group.add_argument('-b')
group.add_argument('-c')
```

You can test it with `parser.parse_args([])`, which will give

```
SystemExit ...
usage: MyFancyCLI [-h] (-a A | -b B | -c C)
MyFancyCLI: error: one of the arguments -a -b -c is required
```

and `parser.parse_args(["-a", "5", "-b", "6"])`

```
usage: MyFancyCLI [-h] (-a A | -b B | -c C)
MyFancyCLI: error: argument -b: not allowed with argument -a
```

Comment: Required options sounds wrong. If it's not optional then it isn't an option but an argument.

Comment: @BlackJack for that just pass False here `parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)`

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-off then stick with your solution (which can be cleaned up a bit), but if you need multiple mutually exclusive definitions, a lookup table is probably your best bet:

cleaned up version of your code:

```
parser.add_argument(-a) 
parser.add_argument(-b) 
parser.add_argument(-c) 
args = parser.parse_args()

if sum((1 for arg in (args.a, args.b, args.c) if arg is not None))>1:
    raise Exception("Found multiple mutually exclusive arguments!")
```

Lookup table approach:

```
parser.add_argument(-a) 
parser.add_argument(-b) 
parser.add_argument(-c) 
args = parser.parse_args()

mutex1 = {args.a, args.b, args.c}
processed_args = set()
mutexes = {args.a : mutex1 , args.b : mutex1 , args.c : mutex1}

for arg in args:
    processed_args.add(arg)
    if arg in mutexes and any((temp in processed_args for temp in mutexes[arg]-{arg})):
        raise Exception("Found multiple mutually exclusive arguments!")
```

Comment: Thanks for that if sum statement. Very elegant and helps me rethink my approach to writing in python.

Comment: @Cordial you're welcome but clearly I need to rethink my approach to programming in general as well; the good ole RTFM (read the fucking manual) would have saved me the trouble of coming up with custom code when there is already a mutex built into argparse (in my defense I've never used argparse before and I assume they're using a similar approach, but still, they already give you that functionallity).